# Quotients of toric varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, toric-varieties, geometric-invariant-theory

This is a follow up of [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297470/is-the-quotient-of-a-toric-variety-by-a-finite-group-still-toric) question. Given a toric variety $X$ with a fan $\Sigma$ and a finite group $G$ acting on $X$, we know that the GIT quotient $X/G$ exists. However, as stated in the answer to the linked question, the quotient need not be a toric variety.

> Are there any conditions for $X$ or $G$ so that the quotient $X/G$ is a toric variety?

Any references are welcome. Thank you in advance.